# 'Break in' vs. 'Break into'

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

> The announcer on the radio suddenly broke **in/into** the middle of a piece of music and informed the audience that there was a storm coming.

After looking up in the dictionary, I think '**in**' is correct here, but the key suggests '**into**'. Which preposition is correct?

Answer (score 4):

The fact that the thing being broken into is a compound noun *(the middle of a piece of music)* might throw some people, so it's easier to just consider...

> *The announcer broke **into** the music*

Some native speakers (me, at least) would be happy with *broke **in on** the music*, because ***to break in*** is an established phrasal verb meaning ***to interrupt***. It doesn't necessarily need to be followed by a noun phrase identifying *what* was broken into (often, it's just an implied *ongoing conversation*). But if the "thing being interrupted" is specified, it should be introduced with its own preposition (i.e. - ***on***).

Personally I see no real syntactic difference between *break into the music* and [*break **into** the house*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22broke%20into%20the%20house%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22break%20into%20the%20house%22) (the "integrity" of the music/house is broken/violated in much the same way). So it's worth noting that Google Books claims 265,000 hits on that link, as compared to just 168 results for [*break **in** the house*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22broke%20in%20the%20house%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22break%20in%20the%20house%22).